# defining floating point constants based on deduced type

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

I have a function template that takes in a 3D vector (anything that has a bracket operator and three elements: `MyCustom3DVector`, `float[3]`, `double*`, etc.) and computes something from it. The signature looks like that:

```
template <typename Vec3> 
constexpr auto compute_stuff(const Vec3& v);
```

In this function, I need to define the constant 1/5. The issue is that the underlying type could be either float or double. I somehow need to extract the underlying type of my `Vec3`. I can do so using

```
using T = std::remove_reference_t<decltype(std::declval<Vec3>()[0])>;
constexpr auto oneFifth = T{1.0/5.0};
```

but this looks ugly and unnecessarily complicated. Is there a better way to proceed?

Comment: what is `Vec3` ? Does it not have a `value_type` member alias?

Comment: You could get rid of the ```declval``` by just using ```decltype(v[0])``` instead. You'll also have to use ```std::remove_cvref_t```, though, since ```v[0]``` may be const. If C++23 is available, ```decltype(auto{v[0]})``` is quite short.

Comment: if it doesnt have a `value_type` you can write a trait of that name so that you can write `value_type_t<Vec3> oneFith{1.0/5.0};`

Comment: `v[0]/v[0]/5` is also one fifth and the correct type.

Comment: @NathanOliver This falls apart if ```v[0]``` is zero, NaN, or infinity.

Comment: It should also be noted that `1/5` cannot be exactly represented in a floating point type so different types will give different answers because of precision.

Comment: Some `Vec3` will be coming from other teams, and won't have any `value_type`, and cannot be modified. `v[0]/v[0]/5` is even less explicit in my opinion. `decltype(v[0])` does not work when `Vec3=float*`.

Comment: *`decltype(v[0])` does not work when `Vec3=float*`* why not?

Comment: There is also the option of `using T = std::decay_t<declval(v[0])>;`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number in this case, the const reference applies to the pointeur and not the content. Hence the bracket operator on `float*` returns a reference to float rather than a float. The declaration of the constant then fails because it does not like the syntax `T{1.0/5.0}`.

Comment: @NathanOliver you mean `std::decay_t<decltype(v[0])>`? Yes you're right, it's a bit cleaner

Comment: @Touloudou Yeah, meant `std::decay_t<decltype(v[0])>`

Answer (score 0):

I would write a type trait for this.

Assuming you want to support pointers to first element of an array, containers that do have a `value_type` and a limited number of containers that do not have a `value_type` member alias:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T,typename = void> struct value_type;
// either its a pointer
template <typename T> struct value_type<T*,void> { using type = T; };
// or it has value_type
template <typename T> struct value_type<T,std::void_t<typename T::value_type>> { using type = typename T::value_type;};

// for convenience
template <typename T> using value_type_t = typename value_type<T>::type;

// ..or it doesn't have a value_type member alias
// some custom container
struct my_vector {
    // no value_type 
    double* data;
};    
// specialization for custom container
template <> struct value_type<my_vector> { using type = double;};


int main()
{
    std::cout << std::is_same_v< int,value_type_t<std::vector<int>>>;
    std::cout << std::is_same_v<double,value_type_t<double*>>;
    std::cout << std::is_same_v<double,value_type_t<my_vector>>;

    // oneFifth
    value_type_t<my_vector> oneFifth{1.0/5.0};
}
```